# List all global variables defined by PHP scripts in a particular directory

Tags: php, debugging, global-variables

I would like to list all the variables in the global scope that scripts that I have written in a particular folder have defined upon their execution. I want to avoid all the clutter of `var_dump($GLOBALS);`

Thanks

Jack

Comment: You are gonna write your own php compiler?

Comment: PHP dosesn't actually care what file a variable was defined in, just whether it's GLOBAL or not, so this simply isn't possible

Comment: Perhaps you want to take a look at PhpDoc - http://phpdoc.org/. This might solve your problem. It can give you a list of all the globals if you document well.

Comment: Oh tis a sad day. Thanks anyway. I want to be able to var_dump php variables on the fly via ajax but $GLOBALS is several MBs